# I want to use the sumifs function with a drop down list to populate data from one sheet to another

Tags: microsoft-excel, dropdownlist

I have data in image one which I want to be visible in image two with the use of a drop down list, where the result changes based on which shop is selected from the drop down list. I tried the sumifs but it is only showing data for shop 1, not for shop 2. Please check the images for reference and formula correction.

[image]

Image 1 with data

[image]

Image 2 with formula

[image]

image three shop2 data is not visible

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing it:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>I4</kbd>

```
=VLOOKUP($H4,INDIRECT($I$1),MATCH(I$3,HEADERS,0),0)
```

---

- Define some ranges to make the formulas works accordingly with respect to the drop-down.
- Range `=$B$4:$F$7` defined as `SHOP1`
- Range `=$B$11:$F$14` defined as `SHOP2`
- Since, the headers remains same for each `SHOPS` then define for one of the `SHOPS` as `HEADERS` for `=$B$3:$F$3`
- Next, use `VLOOKUP()` formula as shown above, fill down and fill right!

---

However, if you are intending to use `SUMIFS()` suggest you to use `SUMPRODUCT()` or `SUM()` based on your `Excel Version`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>I4</kbd>

```
=SUMPRODUCT(INDIRECT($I$1)*(Criteria_Range=$H4)*(I$3=HEADERS))
```

---

- Make some changes to the defined names. As per the followings:

1. Range `=$C$4:$F$7` defined as `SHOP1`
2. Range `=$C$11:$F$14` defined as `SHOP2`
3. Range `=$C$3:$F$3` defined as `HEADERS`
4. Range `=$B$4:$B$7` defined as `Criteria_Range`

- Now, use the above formula and fill down and fill right!

---

Perhaps using `SUMIFS()` the defined named ranges remain same as is like the first method using `VLOOKUP()`

[image]

---

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$1),,MATCH(I$3,HEADERS,0)),INDEX(INDIRECT($I$1),,1),$H4)
```

---

• If you have access to `MS365` then use the following, it is one single formula that will spill the whole array :

```
=LET(
     _Data, VSTACK(EXPAND(SHOP1,,6,"SHOP1"),EXPAND(SHOP2,,6,"SHOP2")),
     _Filtered, FILTER(_Data, TAKE(_Data,,-1)=I1),
     MAKEARRAY(ROWS(H22:H24), COLUMNS(I21:L21), LAMBDA(r,c,
     VLOOKUP(INDEX(H22:H24,r),_Filtered,XMATCH(INDEX(I21:L21,c),HEADERS),0))))
```

---

**Caveat:** Using `INDIRECT()` function is not suggestive, since it is `Volatile` in nature, it slows down the working functionality of `Excel` as well as it will keep recalculating the cells whenever there is a change in any open workbook. You should make some changes to your data structure in order to make your work easy avoiding the use of volatile functions.

---

This can also be achieved using `POWER QUERY` which is available from `Excel 2010+` onwards Windows and MAC.

[image]

---

- First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named for `SHOP1` as `SHOP_1`, for `SHOP2` as `SHOP_2` and for `Channel` as `Channeltbl`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

• For the output:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each Text.StartsWith([Name], "SHOP")),
    #"Expanded Content" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Content", {"Expense Type", "January", "February", "March", "April"}, {"Expense Type", "January", "February", "March", "April"}),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded Content", each ([Name] = CHANNEL)),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows1",{"Name"}),
    #"Filtered Rows2" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Columns", each [Expense Type] <> "Total Budget")
in
    #"Filtered Rows2"
```

---

• For channel:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Channeltbl"]}[Content],
    CHANNEL = Source{0}[CHANNEL]
in
    CHANNEL
```

---

- Remember, you need to paste the above in two different blank queries. Also, the `CHANNEL` query will be a connection while the other needs to be entered in the sheet.

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT(INDIRECT($B$1)*(Sheet2!$B$5:$F$8=Sheet2!$B$6)*(Sheet1!C$3=Sheet1!$C$3:$F$3))   tried this formula but getting  #REF!

Comment: you are getting #REF! because you have not followed the instructions

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT(INDIRECT($B$1)*(Sheet2!$B$5:$B$8=Sheet1!$B4)*(Sheet1!C$3=Sheet2!$C$4:$F$4))                                                                                    I have applied the formula but still getting #REF!  also i am confused where to add the range for shop 1 and shop 2.  Please its humble request can you type the full formula instead of the define names.  you can reffer to the attached images in question for my selected cells.

Comment: @Fahad every single thing is added in the post. If you don't take time to read, it is not my fault. See the explanations and the steps

Comment: @Fahad simple thing you are not understanding, For the `SUMPRODUCT()` i have taken everything from `Column C` onwards which shows you are jumping to the formulas instead of taking time to read

Comment: Here is the [Excel](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2ck34pZctMPXUQ9GfO?e=8V1srA)